# How to get a read confirmation for a post from registered users in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am a noob in WordPress and just built an intranet site. The login to the site is by invite only to our internal employees.

We post important internal communication on the portal and would like to know if a logged in user has read the post and on which date. The idea is to find which users have missed reading which posts?

I tried to search for plugins that will help me to get this information, however, I am drawing a complete blank. Even tried experimenting with various user statistics plugins and programs but to no avail. None of the user statistics packages shows such information.

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mangesh

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) and [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

Create this must-use plugin file and customize:
`wp-content/mu-plugins/read.php`

```
<?php // Requires PHP 5.4+.
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( is_singular() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $read_by = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_read_by', true );
        $read_by = is_array( $read_by ) ? $read_by : [];

        if ( ! isset( $read_by[ $user_id ] ) ) {
            $read_by[ $user_id ] = time();
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_read_by', $read_by );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Will test the solution and respond. Appreciate your help. Was losing hope :-)

Comment: I added the file as suggested. Sorry, but where do I see the data?